# Entity Framework 4.1 collection with references performance impact?

Tags: .net, performance, entity-framework-4.1

I'm running testing scenarios to decide whether or not to implement a system using the Entity Framework and come across an interesting question. I have a collection of 'PersonCollectable' objects stored in 'Person' and each 'PersonCollectable' references to a 'Page'; retrieving the collection provides me all the 'PersonCollectable' objects I want to display but I want to display the name of 'Page' as well. **Will this result in a query for each Page and thus negatively impact performance?**

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual ICollection<PersonCollectable> Collection { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }    
}

public class PersonCollectable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Page Page { get; set; }
    public int PageId { get; set; }
}

public class Page
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the test code to retrieve the information and display the results. Imagine that the collection is filled with at least 500 items, so this might result in 500 additional queries per web request. A development machine can handle this, but I'd like to be aware if this will destroy a published product.

```
Person example = db.People.Single( s => s.Name == "Roel" );
foreach( PersonCollectable exampleCollectable in example.Collection ) {
    Console.WriteLine( "{0} rated {1}", exampleCollectable.Page.Name, exampleCollectable.Rating );
}
```

Please share your insight and help me answer this question, **will this result in a query for each Page and thus negatively impact performance?** Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will result in 500 queries because your way to load navigation properties relies on lazy loading (`virtual` navigation properties).

If you want to load the whole object graph in one single step/roundtrip to the DB you must EF tell that by using `Include` when you run your query:

```
Person example = db.People
    .Include(s => s.Collection.Select(c => c.Page))
    .Single(s => s.Name == "Roel");
```

(The remaining code can stay unchanged.)

In your specific case the recommended way is to use a projection though which means that you only load exactly the properties you need:

```
var example = db.People
    .Where(s => s.Name == "Roel")
    .Select(s => new
    {
        PersonName = s.Name,
        CollectedData = s.Collection.Select(c => new
        {
            PageName = c.Page.Name,
            Rating = c.Rating
        })
    })
    .Single();

Console.WriteLine( "Person {0}:", example.PersonName);
foreach(var item in example.CollectedData)
{
    Console.WriteLine( "{0} rated {1}", item.PageName, item.Rating );
}
```

Instead of using an anonymous type you can also create your own named "View" type and project into it with `Select(s => new MyViewType...)`, etc.

Comment: Thank you! This is a very understandable solution and has given me some more insight in the way EF and Linq work, something to think about when going ahead using EF. Once again, thank you for your swift, accurate and understandable reply.